# Show that $\{a_n(x)\}$ is an increasing sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous, non-negative function on $\mathbb{R}$. Define

$a_n(x) = n\ln(1+\frac{f(x)}{n})$.

I've tried finding $a_{n+1}-a_n$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, but I'm not having any luck. Any suggestions or hints?

Answer (score 3):

Fix $c\ge 0$. Then the function  $g(y)=y\ln (1+c/y)$ is increasing in $y$. 
Indeed, $g(y) = y(\ln (y+c) - \ln y)$ and its derivative is 
$$\ln (y+c) - \ln y + \frac{y}{y+c} - 1\ge  \frac{c}{y+c}+\frac{y}{y+c} -1 =0,$$
where for the inequality we used the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$
a_n(x)=nf(x)(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{3n^3}-\ldots)=f(x)(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}-\ldots).
$$
Therefore,
$$
a_n(x)\leq f(x)(1-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}),\\
a_{n+1}(x) \geq f(x)(1-\frac{1}{2n+2}).
$$

We have $$
\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{3n^2}-\frac{1}{2n+2}=\frac{3n-5}{6n^2(n+1)}\geq0
$$
for $n\geq 2$.
So $a_{n+1}(x)>a_n(x)$ for $n\geq 2$.

The case of $n=1$ can be easily proved seperately.